# How can I get the path of the private key in my machine after I generate the CSR from Digicert?

Tags: encryption, private-key, public-key, csr, digicert

I ordered the SSL/TLS certificate from DigiCert CA (certificate Authority) by generating the CSR. But in order to install the certificate I could not get the generated private key in my machine. There is no path selection during the generation of the key. So how can I get where the key is located in my machine?

I tried to look each folder in my machine, but I could not find it.